# KeyError: 'color' in networkX

Tags: python, networkx, keyerror

I am doing a tutorial on network X: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/networkx-python-graph-tutorial

This is the following code:

```
import itertools
import copy
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edgelist = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew    /e570c38bcc72a8d102422f2af836513b/raw/89c76b2563dbc0e88384719a35cba0dfc04cd522/edgelist_sleeping_giant.csv')

nodelist = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/f989e10af17fb4c85b11409fea47895b/raw/a3a8da0fa5b094f1ca9d82e1642b384889ae16e8/nodelist_sleeping_giant.csv')

g = nx.Graph()

## Add edges and edge attributes 
for i, elrow in edgelist.iterrows():
g.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], attr_dict=elrow[2:].to_dict())

## Add nodes and node attributes
for i, nlrow in nodelist.iterrows():
   g.nodes[nlrow['id']].update(nlrow[1:].to_dict())


##Visualization

# Define node positions data structure (dict) for plotting
node_positions = {node[0]: (node[1]['X'], -node[1]['Y']) for node in g.nodes(data=True)}

# Define data structureof edge colors for plotting
edge_colors = [e[2]["color"] for e in g.edges(data=True)]
```

gives me a KeyError: 'color' although in the data provided, the column is called color so it has nothing to do with case sensitivity

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "attr_dict" key as the "color" key is nested inside it.

```
edge_colors = [e[2]["attr_dict"]["color"] for e in g.edges(data=True)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful since I am new to python and networkX